# How can I update the contents of a list, dictionary, or dataframe while making several asyncronous calls?

Tags: python, dataframe, asynchronous, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am building a DataFrame (pandas) that contains some information inside of it. At some point, once the DataFrame is completed, I need to perform some calculations on each DataFrame.

Currently, you can say that is looks something like this:

```py
def perform_calculations(df: DataFrame):
        calculations = df.text.apply([lambda x: calculate(x)])
        df["calculations"] = calculations
        return df
```

However, though this worked for some time, it has become really slow. The `calculate` function makes some API requests, and as the size of the DataFrame has grown larger, so has the time it takes to complete this.

The `calculate` function does not care about the other texts, meaning this work can be parallelized. However, I am unsure how I can update a DataFrame in a parallelized manner. I supposed I don't need to update the DataFrame until the end and can instead collect the information into a list of some sort, then update the DataFrame?

But how would I do this? How can I call `calculate` asynchronously and collect all of its return values, then update the DataFrame?

Answer (score 1):

I think easiest way would be spawn X `calculate()` tasks and then using `asyncio.gather()` to wait for the results (of course, using `asyncio.Semaphore` to limit concurrency to not DDOS the API server):

```py
import asyncio
import pandas as pd

sem = asyncio.Semaphore(2)  # limit concurrency to 2 (to not hammer the API server)

async def calculate(df, index):
    async with sem:
        t = df.loc[index, 'text']

        # simulate the API call
        # for this example make the text only uppercase
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        t = t.upper()

        df.loc[index, 'Calculated'] = t

async def main():
    df = pd.read_csv('your_data.csv')

    print('df before')
    print(df)

    await asyncio.gather(*{calculate(df, i) for i in df.index})

    print()
    print('df after')
    print(df)

asyncio.run(main())
```

After 2 seconds (because we've limited the concurrency to 2 and have 4 rows) it prints:

```
df before
   Column1  Column2   text
0        1       10  text1
1        3       30  text3
2        4       40  text4
3        2       20  text2

df after
   Column1  Column2   text Calculated
0        1       10  text1      TEXT1
1        3       30  text3      TEXT3
2        4       40  text4      TEXT4
3        2       20  text2      TEXT2
```